# Import from SQL Scripts Always Fails

Tags: visual-studio-2015, database-project

I have exported my database to SQL Scripts using SQL Management Studio both as  a single file, and as multiple files. In both cases when I create an empty Database Project in VS.net 2015 and choose "Import ... Script", and choose either my one big script, or the folder of multiple scripts does not create any artefacts in the project.

The log for a multi-file import file gives

```
08/06/2016 15:33:18 This log contains information about the import operation of the script 'dbo.SOMETABLENAME.Table.sql' into project 'MYPROJECTNAME' on computer 'MYCOMPUTER' by user'philliph.
08/06/2016 15:33:33 Started importing file: C:\Users\philliph\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp29BA.tmp 
08/06/2016 15:33:33 File name C:\Users\philliph\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp29BA.tmp (size: 5800811)
08/06/2016 15:33:33 Parsing import script
08/06/2016 15:34:07 A summary of the import was saved to the following location: MYSOURCELOCATION\Import Script Logs\dbo_FIRSTTABLENAME__20160608023318.log
08/06/2016 15:34:07 Click Finish to continue...
```

And the log file for a single file import gives no more useful information. I've tried exporting from SQL Server using ASCII or UNICODE formats and the scripts themselves look fine. I can import into the Database Project directly from the database itself, but don't want to do this because I have a lot of SQL Replication database artefacts I don't want to put under source code control, and the Script Export in Management Studio allows me to filter those out.

Has anyone managed to import from script successfully or is there some secret to this ? I notice the log seems to create a large temp file, but its deleted as soon as the tool completes its processing (which takes a couple of minutes) so I cant tell what it contains.

Comment: I've managed to use import from script for one-off new objects, but have never tried it for populating the initial project. For that I always used either a dacpac or a direct connection. The dacpac actually gave me better success as it tended to ignore dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I never found a way of successfully importing from scripts. I was attempting to do this to avoid importing the replication artefacts from my live database. Following an idea posted in http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/using-visual-studio-database-projects-in-real-life I used the Schema Compare tool to generate a compare between my live database and an empty Database Project. This tool allowed me to filter out any database objects I wanted before it applied the comparison to my database project.

Although it didn't solve my original question, this workaround might be useful for others.